# angular 5 paypal integration

Tags: angular, paypal, paypal-sandbox, angular5

I am using angular 5, and I need to integrate paypal checkout, so I am following below procedure

```
run 'npm install xcomponent'
run 'npm install paypal-checkout'
```

script added to index.html

`<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>`

At app.module.ts, exported and imported (in NgModule imports list) a new Module
declare

> const paypal:any;
>
> export const PayPalButtonModule =
>   paypal.Button.driver( 'angular2', {
>
> Component, NgModule, ElementRef,
>   NgZone  });

but I had error in the app.module.ts for red underline error in this **Component, NgModule, ElementRef, NgZone** in above code, How to implement paypal in angular 5 please help to solve this problem

Comment: **Angular 5 release**  :O . I am similarly thinking about IPhone-8 and IPhone-X release

Comment: Any other solution is there?

Comment: check https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues/368

Comment: paypal is not defined this error shown now

Comment: If you are using Angular 5 check this easy solution to integrate paypal: http://tphangout.com/angular-5-paypal-express-checkout/